# Does $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+(x\sin x)^2}\ dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

> Does the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+(x\sin x)^2} \ \, \mathrm{d}x$$ converge?

I know that I need to look at:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{1}{1+(x\sin x)^2}\ \, \mathrm{d}x$$

but not sure how utilize this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between $x=n\pi$ and $x=n\pi-1/n$, we have $|\sin x|<1/n$, so $f(x)>1/(1+\pi^2)$.  How does that affect the total integral.

Comment: I guess we could look at $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2\left|\sin x\right|} \ dx$. Is that your intention?

Comment: No, sum the narrow little pieces.

Comment: I see. Thank you @Micael.